# Can't Turn Off Swipe Between Pages!

Tags: macos, system-settings, mouse

I recently picked up the new Magic Mouse 2.  Since then, the 'Swipe Between Pages' has started working on it's own.  With the old mouse, I turned it off, as I was constantly flipping through web pages accidentally.

Even though the prefs say it is deactivated... it won't stop!  I tried turning it on and back off... no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same issue.  I'm on a Macbook Pro and changed the settings for the trackpad.  This changed the mouse behavior.  Not a true solution, but works for me.